# Wait for coroutine to finish to handle user click

Tags: android, kotlin-coroutines

I'm making a system of "sessions" where the user can launch, finish and view his session.
The user go through a first fragment to create his session and then go into a fragment "in session".
If he return to the main menu before finishing his session, I want him to go directly to "in session" without going through the "new session" fragment.

All session data are stored into a local database and I use Kotlin coroutines to fetch data from the db (see code example below)

> It's my first time using coroutine, and I will admit it's a bit fuzzy
>   for me, all the help is welcome

**The problem is** that when the user press the bouton to navigate, the coroutine finish **after** the verification to see if there is a current session, that lead to verify a null object or the previous session of the current session, and so navigate to a the "new session" fragment

> What I need is a way to wait for the coroutine to finish and then
>   handle the button click

All the code wrote here is **contain inside inside the viewModel**.
This is how I setup the Job/Scope

```
private var viewModelJob = Job()
private val uiScope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main + viewModelJob)
```

And this is how I launch the coroutine:

```
private fun initializeLastSession() {
    uiScope.launch {
    lastSession.value = getLastSessionFromDatabase()
    }
}

private suspend fun getLastSessionFromDatabase(): Session? {
    return withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
        var session = database.getLastSession()
        session
    }
}
```

The verification is made inside this function

```
fun isSessionActive(): Boolean {
//Simplified
    if (lastSession.value = null) {
        return false
    } else if (...) {
        return true
    } else {
        return false
    }
```

This last function "isSessionActive" is called from an **if** statement from the fragment itlsef, when the user press the navigation button.
If it's true then it navigate to "InSession", else in "newSession"

I've seen multiple way of waiting for a coroutine to finish but none match the way I launch it, and even less have a solution that has worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Would you allow me with a simple example unrelated to your code? But strongly related to the problem:

```
uiScope.launch{
 withContext(Dispatchers.IO){
  val dataFromDatabase = getSomeDataFromDatabase()
  if (dataFromDatabase.notEmpty()){ //or something
    withContext(Dispatchers.Main){
     //send data to fragment here :)
    }
   }
 }
}
```

EDIT:

Since you stated you are in the `ViewModel`, you don't need to return any value, you need to observe that changed value:

```
//on top of your ViewModel class: 

val yourVariableName: MutableLiveData<Boolean> = MutableLiveData()

//than in your method: 
    uiScope.launch{
     withContext(Dispatchers.IO){
      val dataFromDatabase = getSomeDataFromDatabase()
      if (dataFromDatabase.notEmpty()){ //or something
        withContext(Dispatchers.Main){
         if (lastSession.value = null) {
        yourVariableName.value = false
    } else if (...) {
        yourVariableName.value = true
    } else {
        yourVariableName.value = false
    }
        }
       }
     }
    }
```

And than in your fragment:

```
//after you have successfully instantiated the `ViewModel`: 
mViewModel.yourVariableName.observe(this , Observer{ valueYouAreObserving->
 // and here you have the value true ore false 
 Log.d("Tag", $valueYouAreObserving)
})
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, I think I've understand the code but i'm not really sure to what to do with it..
The probleme is that I don't do any ui change, I just return a boolean to my fragment to determine if I need to go to one fragment or the other

Comment: just needed to update the comment not to get you confused

Comment: Okay, just a last problem, where you say to send data to fragment, in fact in the fragment i call this function who is supposed to return a boolean. In this function I have a **when** statement that decide if I **return** false or true.   
How do I "transmit" this return boolean out of the withContext and uiScope.launch ?  
I tried return@withContext but the IDE doesn't like the fact that there is 2 of them  
I also tried to put a return in front of "uiScope.launch" but it return a Job
Sorry for the mistakes or the miss of information, been on this for 2 full days and getting really tilted

Comment: I have edit the post to explain a bit what I've say in my last comment

Comment: How are you communication with a fragment. are you inside a `ViewModel` or is that a presenter?

Comment: Yes, all the code I wrote in the question is contain inside the viewModel of the fragment

Comment: Oh but that's pretty easy than. Don't return value. Just define a `MutableLiveData` of type `Boolean` and observe it on the fragment. I will update the aswer.

Comment: I eddited the answer, check it out.

Comment: Okay I've understand your solution but it doesn't work because i think i'm still missing something. I have change the signature of my function "isSessionActive()" to return nothing and just update the value.
Do I put the binding.button.setOnClickListener into the Observer just after It called "isSessionActive" (try that and didn't work, button just not worked)
My question is, on the fragment side, where do I call this function to update the boolean value before using it on the setOnClickListener to determine where i'm navigating

Comment: No. Your `onClickListener` must not be inside the observer. Use it like this: `button.setOnClickListener{viewModel.updateValue()}` and then observe the changes as I explained.

Comment: I'm sorry I still don't get it, in the 'button.setOnClickListener' I do update the value like you said, but in the same onClickListener how do I access the value returned by the Observer to my 'if(boolean) {Navigate here} else {Navigate there}' ? I tried putting the Observer inside the setOnClickListener but it seems so wrong and it was, app randomly crash when navigating

Comment: The observer will return that value from onclick listener don't worry. That's why the `ViewModel` is

Comment: I still don't get what i'm supposed to put in the if() .. Just to be sure to be on the same page: In the fragment (Not the wiewModel this part is okay), I got the `viewModel.MyBoolean.observe(this, Observer { //What do i put in here too ?})` and the, down that i got `button.setOnClickListener{viewModel.update; if(WhatBoolean?) {NavigateTo1} else {NavigateTo2}} `

Comment: `//What do i put in here` too on this line you put whatever you need to do after you get the boolean value from the `viewModel` which could be true or false depending on your case

Comment: Still don't work :/ The thing is I don't do anything with the boolean, I just check it in my `button.setOnClickListener` to see where i'm supposed to navigate. And so I want it to update (Fetch last session from database and see if it's null, still active or finished) before the `if` in this `button.setOnClickListener`. I tried having a Boolean variable in my fragment and `viewModel.boolean.observe(this, Observer { myBoolean = it})` But on the first time that I create a session, return to main menu and recheck this boolean on `button.setOnClickListener` it isn't updated yet

Comment: I'm sorry, you need to get more into `LiveData` and MVVM in order to deal with this situation.

Comment: Well thanks for the help you provided, it's still better than where I start, i'll continue to fight this problem

Comment: You have all you need on the answer btw.

Comment: I've played around with the log and all that and problem is still the same, the observer update the boolean only after the navigation, because the update fonction called just before the navigation take too much time to update the mutableLiveData, wich bring to the same problem as starting..
I "fixed" the probleme by calling the viewModel.update in the Observer but; like expected it just create a infinite loop and made the app crash after a moment

Comment: Well I've finally found a 'way' to solve it but it's more about getting around the problem than really fix it: I just put my `if` statement inside a `Handler().postDelayed` of 20ms. It's a Barbarian way but it work until a found a more elegant solution